# Correct sql query in CodeIgniter is giving an error

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I am running a query from CodeIgniter, I am getting this error.

```
    A Database Error Occurred
    Error Number: 42000/263
    [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must specify 
    table to select from.
    SELECT *
    Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/4hifi/system/database/DB_driver.php
```

Which is confusing cause exactly the same query executed directly in SQL-Server is giving correct results.

I am using CodeIgniter 3.1.9 , I already tried to inject $username variable to query in different ways, all are giving the same error.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "select date, g1.product_name, g2.order_amount, g1.price, g1.id, g1.order_id, g1.action from dbo.orders g1 inner join (select product_name, SUM( order_amount) as order_amount from dbo.orders where action=1 and confirmed!=1 group by product_name) g2 on g2.product_name = g1.product_name where g1.confirmed !=1 and g1.kontrahent = ? and action = 1";

        $db2->query($sql, $username);


        $result = $db2->get()->result_array();

        return $result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$db2->query($sql, $username);` line itself should return the required result.No need to do `db->get()` in case of raw queries.

Comment: Yes, I made change in code according to your answer and now is working, thank you very much ;)

$query = $db2->query($sql, $username);
$result = $query->result_array();

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing that in two steps. You should use something like this

```
$sql = "select date, g1.product_name, g2.order_amount, g1.price, g1.id, g1.order_id, g1.action from dbo.orders g1 inner join (select product_name, SUM( order_amount) as order_amount from dbo.orders where action=1 and confirmed!=1 group by product_name) g2 on g2.product_name = g1.product_name where g1.confirmed !=1 and g1.kontrahent = ? and action = 1";

    $result = $sql->result_array();

    return $result;
```